# Microsoft Dynamics CRM - Plug-in C# - add record to entity collection

Tags: c#, plugins, dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-crm-online

Plug-In, C#, Microsoft Dynamics CRM Online

I want to add a record (let's call it "sampleRecord") to an Entity Collection (let's call it "sampleCollection"), but somehow I can't make it work. I found this solution on the internet, but when I check the total record count via ITracingService, it's still 0.

my solution so far:

```
EntityCollection sampleCollection = new EntityCollection();
sampleCollection.Entities.Add(sampleRecord);
```

and that's how I checked the total record count:

```
tracingService.Trace("total record count: " + sampleCollection.TotalRecordCount.ToString());
```

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're looking at the wrong value. `TotalRecordCount` is a result from the query execution (not the count of `.Entities`. If you use `.Entities.Count()` you should get the correct value, as shown here:

```
var entityCollection = new EntityCollection();

Console.WriteLine(entityCollection.Entities.Count()); // 0

entityCollection.Entities.Add(new Entity());

Console.WriteLine(entityCollection.Entities.Count()); // 1
```